# What is the normal voltage of 5-wire oxygen sensor (lambda probe)?

Tags: fuel-system, o2-sensor, fuel-injection, opel, gasoline-direct-injection

I have got a 2007 Opel Vectra GTS 2.2 Direct car (which still has a high pressure fuel pump problem, yet to be solved). Petrol, 114 kW, engine Z22YH.

After getting an P0130-52 (No Plausibility between O2 Sensor 1 Bank 1 and O2 sensor 2 Bank 1) error, I started monitoring voltages of O2 sensors (via Opcom). One which is pre-cat was about 1.5 (up to 2) volts on idle. I've been told that lambda probes should not give more than 1 volt, so I've decided to replace it. Now it shows 5 volts. The ECU does not give any errors regarding that. In case of revving up, I get the same P0130-52 which seems to be because of the same high pressure fuel pump problem. The fuel mix seems to be always rich.

I've ordered a new pump, but I don't know if is it safe to replace it while this problem exists.

I'm quite new to cars, sorry.

Comment: is this the same as the 2.2 gm gdi engine? if it is there's a known problem with a seal on the high pressure pump leaking causing a rich condition and high crankcase pressure. there may also be some abnormal noise in the engine. along with fuel contamination in the oil. I wouldn't replace the high pressure fuel pump until you can prove any of the above symptoms are true or if the pressure is out of spec. afr sensors are 5v sensors i'm unsure of the specs for your car. if you can consult a factory service manual.

Comment: Thanks @Ben, your comment is useful! Yes, this is a 2.2 GM GDI engine. I've bought this car about 5 months ago and one of the first things my friend (works at repair shop) noticed is that oil has petrol in it. Due to defective pump (getting to LIMP mode at 120 km/h or ~3500 rpm) I had it and the regulator (both are used, total ~400 € ) replaced, but it did not solve the problem. Well, symptoms initially got better, but still getting to limp mode, even on smaller RPMs. Pressure at feedback is way less than desired (normal at idle, regulator seems to be working).
I can't tell if noise is bad.

Comment: @Ben (writing again since I failed to tag properly).
P. S. I've checked the oil -- yes, it has petrol in it and the total amount is off limits.